# Как составить регулярку preg_match?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Сделать регулярку: текст-любое количество пробелов-цифры через запятую. Пример:

```
example 12,14,15,25,323
```

Должен парсить

```
[1]=>example
[2]=>12
[3]=>14
[4]=>15
```

итд

А то у меня все так грустно :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = 'example 12,14,15,25,323 example-two 142,14,15,25,323, etc';
preg_match_all('/([\d\w\-]+),?/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: короче, как у меня, пользователь забивает текст с наименованиями и коэфф., это все идет в базу.
мне надо чтобы результаты парсились так
$matches[0]=>([0]=>'example_one 1,3,5', [1]=>'1', [2]=>'3', [3]=>'5');
$matches[1]=>([0]=>'example_two 2,6,5', [1]=>'2', [2]=>'6', [3]=>'5');

Comment: Используйте две регулярки.

Comment: Ну я так и делаю :) Просто хотел вариант с 1 :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', 'example 12,14,15,25,323');
```

Comment: только я не уточнил, тект поступает для парса такой: "'example 12,14,15,25,323 example-two 142,14,15,25,323, etc"

Comment: preg_match:
/(example).([\d{1,3}].*)/i

1 : example 13,14,15,16
1.1 : example
1.2 : 13,14,15,16

а потом

preg_split:
'/[\d,]+/'

тогда да получается, а как сделать в 1 регулярку?